# Inline object position in XAML WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to make `checkbox` and `textbloxk` parallel or inline in my XAML WP8, but it seems the `checkbox` is upside and the `textblock` is below the `checkbox`. Any suggest how?

```
<Grid Margin="0,522,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                                <CheckBox  x:Name="Accept"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="I Accept Terms and Conditions" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `TextBlock` for this. Set `CheckBox.Content`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Accept" Content="I Accept Terms and Conditions"/>
```

and for other cases if want to stack elements horizontally then set `Orientation="Horizontal"` on you `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
```

Comment: I'm using the `Grid` over the `stackpanel` so the vertical and the horizontal alignment has been set by the `Grid`.